# I teach mathematics vs. I teach Mathematics

Tags: word-choice

"Currently I am coaching younger pupils in the subjects Mathematics, English and Latin."

First question: Are the listed subjects meant to be in capital letters or not?

Second question: Is there a comma after currently?

Third question: I would suggest changing the sentence to "Currently I teach younger pupils Mathematics, English and Latin." But is there a way of using the word "coaching" and still make it sound good? It sounds a bit "irregular".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital letters for "English" is required, as it is formed from the proper noun "England". Similarly "Latin" is the name of the language and has a capital.

The Capital letter for "mathematics" is optional.  If you are refering to the name of the course it should have a capital. If you are referring to the general topic then it doesn't have a capital.  But many people capitalise it anyway, for consistency with "English" "Latin" etc. Most people won't care (or even notice).

A comma after currently is possible and recommended in some styles. However it doesn't seem to be essential and I would follow the advice "If in doubt, leave it out!"

Its up to you to decide if you are teaching or coaching. The words are a little different in meaning. But we can't write your CV for you. Just decide what you do and write that.

Comment: I care (and notice). Capitals for names of courses, and of languages. Lower case otherwise. "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds" - Ralph Waldo Emerson.